# ios - Draw and Delete lines with SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to draw a line via drag finger, now I can draw lines from first tap position to current position. But I can't delete the line I draw before. I use this code to delete lines.

```
for line in self.children {
    line.removeFromParent()
}
```

But all of the deleted lines will appear when add a new line.

There's my code below.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var label : SKLabelNode?
    private var spinnyNode : SKShapeNode?

    // For Line
    var startPoint: CGPoint?
    var path = CGMutablePath()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    }


    func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
        print("touchDown")
        startPoint = pos
    }

    func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {
        print("touchMoved")

        for line in self.children {
            line.removeFromParent()
        }

        plotLine(atPoint: startPoint!, toPoint: pos)
    }

    func plotLine(atPoint start: CGPoint, toPoint end: CGPoint) {
        path.move(to: start)
        path.addLine(to: end)

        let temp_shape = SKShapeNode()
        temp_shape.path = path
        temp_shape.strokeColor = UIColor.white
        temp_shape.lineWidth = 2

        self.addChild(temp_shape)
    }
```

Comment: Where is the definition of the node that you call 'line'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
var startPoint: CGPoint?
var tempLine: SKShapeNode!
var completedLines: [SKShapeNode] = []

func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    print("touchDown")
    startPoint = pos

    tempLine = SKShapeNode()
    tempLine.strokeColor = UIColor.white
    tempLine.lineWidth = 2
    self.addChild(tempLine)
}

func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    print("touchMoved")

    plotLine(atPoint: startPoint!, toPoint: pos)
}

func touchUp(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {
    completedLines.append(tempLine)
    tempLine = nil
}

func plotLine(atPoint start: CGPoint, toPoint end: CGPoint) {
    var path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: start)
    path.addLine(to: end)

    tempLine.path = path
}

func deleteLine(atIndex index: Int) {
    completedLines[index].removeFromParent()
    completedLines.remove(at: index)
}

func deleteLastLine() {
    if let lastLine = completedLines.last {
        lastLine.removeFromParent()
        completedLines.dropLast()
    }
}
```

So each of your tempLines will now be saved in array. And you can call delete functions where do you need lines to be deleted. For Example, if you need to delete the previous line before you start a new one you want to do it at touchDown like so:

```
func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    self.deleteLastLine()

    print("touchDown")
    startPoint = pos

    tempLine = SKShapeNode()
    tempLine.strokeColor = UIColor.white
    tempLine.lineWidth = 2
    self.addChild(tempLine)
}
```